# HTML tables form MYSQL with PHP while using $WPDB

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, custom-wordpress-pages

Hi I am trying to create a table with PHP inside a wordpress shortcode while using the $wpdb connection to the MYSQL table. I have written up /found how to do this with the basic PHP and traditional connection but what I have coded isnt working I am sure I have missed something. Can someone please tell me  in the code below where I have gone wrong? Thanks.

global $wpdb;

```
$wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM wp_wpdatatable_4"));
    $result=mysql_query(query);
    $numfields = mysql_num_fields($result);
    echo "<table border=1><tr>";

    for ($i=0; $i < $numfields; $i++) // Header
    { echo '<th>'.mysql_field_name($result, $i).'</th>'; }

    echo "</tr>";

    while
    ($res=mysql_fetch_row($result))   //you may use mysql_fatch_array($result) which can hendel both $res[name] and $res[1]
    {
    echo"
    <tr>
    <td>  $res[0]</td>
    <td>  $res[1]</td>
    <td>  $res[2]</td>
    .
    .
    .
    </tr>";
    }

    echo"</table>";

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code uses a combination of $wpdb & php mysql functions.

Maybe just use $wpdb

```
global $wpdb;

$data_table_4 = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_wpdatatable_4" ); 

if ( ! empty( $data_table_4 ) ) {
    echo '<table>';
    if ( ! empty( $data_table_4 ) ) {
        foreach ( $data_table_4 as $data_table_4_row ) { 
            echo '<tr>';
            foreach ( $data_table_4_row as $row_item ) {
                echo '<td>' . $row_item . '</td>';
            }
            echo '</tr>';
        }
    }
    echo '</table>';    
}
```

Comment: Thanks. How does the above build the table in HTML then? The great suggestion calls the table information just fine but in addition to calling I also needed to have the code to build the table which is what I thought I had in the TR and TD tags etc?

Comment: Did you manage to get it figured out? I've edited my answer; hope it helps